# Check for User log in when launching an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app in iOS and am using firebase for my user login/validation etc. I want to be able to login, and if a user closes the app and then re-opens it, they are not forced to re-log in every time. Currently I have this code in my AppDelegate:

```
func setRootViewController(){
   if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
      self.presentTabBar()
    } else {
      self.presentLoginViewController()
    }
}

func presentTabBar(){

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier :"myTabBar")
    self.present(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

However because this is in my AppDelegate I'm getting an error on my line self.present(viewController...) saying that AppDelegate has no memeber called self. I understand that this is because self is only available to ViewControllers.

How can I implement this functionality from within my AppDelegate file?

Comment: you should save login credentials on user login first time. when he open second time keep stay on splash in background resend login request to firebase if saved login credentials has account go to mainVC other wise LoginVC. use user defaults to save credentials.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `self.present(viewController, animated: true)` you can use

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: thanks, which screen should I set as my Initial View Controller? I would've thought that because this functionality is in my AppDelegate it doesn't matter but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.

Comment: i don't know what controllers you have and which you want to display initialy

Comment: so I have a login ViewController, and then my home ViewController. I want the application to open and allow users to go straight to the home ViewController if they've already signed in before, but if no I want it to divert them to the LoginViewController

Comment: You can set the rootViewController in two different scenerios one as LoginController if not logged in else you can go with home controller as root

Comment: @Rohi How do I do that exactly? Thanks for that tip, I wasn't aware this functionality was possible

Comment: @Lu_ That hasn't worked. If I launch the app it brings me straight to the Home, and if I log out and close the app. It brings me back to Home - it doesn't force me to log in

Comment: `Auth.auth().currentUser != nil` this part is not working not my solution

Comment: @Lu_ that code is straight from Firebase's documentation so I reckon it's fine. Maybe I'm not calling it/accessing it properly. I'll look into it

Comment: did you even try to use debugger? you just have user there. If you want always to force to login, just set login as initial viewcontroller and dont even use this code you have now

Comment: @ Eoghan Casey, i have posted answer down you can check with that.

Comment: @Rohi : Offended it might look but OP must have received multiple notifications of your answer and your own comment on your answer. It is not necessary to ask for his attention everywhere.

Comment: @ Nitish, I have posted my comment only in one place. You can check again.

Comment: @Rohi : Of course, since you deleted your comment on your answer. Please remember that even if your deleted comments a not visible, StackOverflow keeps track of those. Also, please don't lie :)

Answer (score 0):

```
      func setRootViewController() {
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                   UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nil
                   UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = homeViewController
                  UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
           } else {
               UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nil
               UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = loginViewController
              UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
         }
      }
```